# browser back button go back follow a custom url list?

Tags: javascript, django, browser, html5-history

I have seen [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/), it seems just work on current page:
such as:

```
www.mysite.com
www.mysite.com/?state=1
www.mysite.com/?state=2
www.mysite.com/?state=3
www.mysite.com/?state=4
www.mysite.com/?state=3
```

It can make back button back follow state from large to small only on the same page.
What I want is:

```
www.mysite.com/center/?state=1
www.mysite.com/product-list/?state=2
www.mysite.com/product-detail-manage-form/?state=3
```

`center` can not return to `product-list`, and `product-list` can not return to  `product-detail-manage-form`.

Because a user can edit or delete a product at `product-detail-manage-form` page, and server will redirect he to `product-list` page after form submit.
I don't want he return to `product-detail-manage-form` by clicking back button on `product-list` page.
Is there any easy way to achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Try using javascript to manipulate the browser history: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

This way you can control the history stack and which pages the users can get to using the back button